# Displaying HTML content in a Field in blackberry

Tags: javascript, html, json, blackberry, browserfield

I am getting JSON response from the server..Inside that JSON string i am having HTML content which i need to display in a field..

Can anyone help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `eval` the JSON response, though for better security adding [JSON parsing support](http://www.json.org/js.html) is fairly simple, try the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.  Then just use normal JS notation to extract your HTML string and insert it into your text field.

Note that:

1. The Blackberry browser didn't support [XMLHttpRequest](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/8857/Feature_AJAX_512507_11.jsp) until 4.6, for example the [Curve 8310](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/board/message?message.uid=67550) does not support it.
2. Javascript is not enabled by default on the Blackberry browser, if you have corporate setup you can enable it through an [MDS policy rule](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/7229/MDS_Browser_JavaScript_Enabled_204041_11.jsp)
3. If you've got the above two covered, be careful with Javascript libraries as you can easily exhaust the device memory simply interpreting them (with less than 300k of JS IMX)

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878551/display-simple-html-in-a-native-blackberry-application) for more detail on how to display HTML content in a BlackBerry field by using a V4.5.0 BrowserContent class.