# How to show html text in BlackBerry?

Tags: html, blackberry

Is there any way to show LOCAL html string in my BB application?

For example: I have a string

`"<b>text-text-text</b> <A href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</A>`"

How can I parse and show it as

**text-text-text** [link](http://stackoverflow.com)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a BrowserField to render content in your application as a Field.  In order to render HTML provided as a String rather than a URL, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878551/display-simple-html-in-a-native-blackberry-application/1881572#1881572) which involves mocking an HttpConnection.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.microedition.io.Connection;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser;
import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.BrowserSession;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.browser.field.*;
import net.rim.device.api.browser.plugin.BrowserPageContext;
import net.rim.device.api.io.Base64OutputStream;
import net.rim.device.api.io.http.HttpHeaders;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Application;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Status;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextField;



final class bFieldExample extends UiApplication 

{
    private static final String REFERER = "referer";

    public static final HttpConnection Utilities = null;

//  private static final HttpConnection HttpConnection = null;  

    private RenderingSession rs;  

    private MainScreen ms;

    private HttpConnection  conn;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        bFieldExample app = new bFieldExample();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();

    }

    public bFieldExample()
    {
        ms = new MainScreen();
        pushScreen(ms);
        rs = RenderingSession.getNewInstance();
        String s = "<b>text-text-text</b> <A href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</A>"

        //rs.getRenderingOptions().setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,RenderingOptions.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, true);
        //LabelField l = new LabelField("Browser",LabelField.ELLIPSIS|LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        ms.setTitle(new LabelField("Browser",LabelField.ELLIPSIS|LabelField.USE_ALL_WIDTH));        
        myThread thread = new myThread(s);
        thread.start();
    }


    class myThread extends Thread
    {

        private String _url;

        myThread(String url)
        {
                _url=url;

        }

        public void run()
        {
            try {

                ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                Base64OutputStream boutput = new Base64OutputStream( output );                
                output.write( "data:text/html;base64,".getBytes() );
                boutput.write( _url.getBytes() );
                boutput.flush();
                boutput.close();
                output.flush();
                output.close();

                BrowserSession bSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
                bSession.displayPage( output.toString() );

                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That will open a new browser -- I think the author of the question is looking for a solution that renders the HTML inside the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
myBrowserField.displayContent("<b>text-text-text</b> <A href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</A>", "http://localhost");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
BrowserField myBrowserField;
myBrowserField = new BrowserField();
add(myBrowserField);
String content ="<html><head></head><body>"+
    "<b>text-text-text</b> <A href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</A>"+
    "</body></html>";
myBrowserField.displayContent(content,"");//"http://localhost"
```