# how to display these text on blackberry and how to show the hyperlinks

Tags: blackberry

```
 <!DOCTYPE html
 PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
   <html> 
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
  <title>A history of Canoe Cove /</title> 
  </head> 
 <body> 



  <div class="tei"> 




     <p> 
        A History of 

     </p> 



     <p> 
        The 
        General
        Stores




     </p> 



     <p> 
        There were several general stores in our <a class="search orgName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.orgNameTERM:%22Cove%22+AND+dc.type:collection">Cove</a> at

        different times. The one that lasted longest was at

        the Corner across from the school and it had many

        owners. Who established it is unclear but John


        MacKenzie, the piper, who was also a shoe maker

        lived there. He was a relative of the present day

        MacKenzies of <a class="search placeName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.placeNameTERM:%22Canoe Cove%22+AND+dc.type:collection">Canoe Cove</a>. 
        William
        MacKay
         who

        married 
        Christena
        MacLean
         was operating it when it

        burned down and a store which had belonged to Neil

        "Cooper" MacLean was moved across to the site. This

        was later bought by <span class="persName"><a class="search persName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.persNameTERM:%22MacCannell+Neil%22+AND+dc.type:collection"> 
              Neil
              MacCannell
              </a></span> of 
        Long Creek
        , a

        schoolteacher who taught in the <a class="search orgName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.orgNameTERM:%22Cove%22+AND+dc.type:collection">Cove</a> for a few years.


        <span class="persName"><a class="search persName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.persNameTERM:%22MacNevin+Hector%22+AND+dc.type:collection"> 
              Hector
              MacNevin
              </a></span> from <a class="search placeName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.placeNameTERM:%22St. Catherines%22+AND+dc.type:collection">St. Catherines</a> operated it for a

        year while it still belonged to <span class="persName"><a class="search persName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.persNameTERM:%22MacCannell+Neil%22+AND+dc.type:collection"> 
              Neil
              MacCannell
              </a></span> because


        Neil had accepted a job in <a class="search placeName" target="_blank" href="http://islandlives.net/fedora/ilives_book_search/tei.placeNameTERM:%22Charlottetown%22+AND+dc.type:collection">Charlottetown</a> as clerk of

        the Court. Later 
        Mrs.
        John
        Angus
         Darrach bought it

        and she and her son George ran it for years until both

        had health problems, and had to close the store after

        which closing it never reopened. After George died

        and his wife Hazel moved to Montague to live with her

        family the building was sold to 
        Robert
        Patterson
        . Rob

        lived in it for a few years, making many improvements           

        then sold it to Kirk McAleer.

     </p> 









  </div>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878551/display-simple-html-in-a-native-blackberry-application/1881572#1881572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the BlackBerry Browser.