# Blackberry - How to print HTML String in a field

Tags: html, string, blackberry, browserfield

I have an HTML String like
`<p>something</p> etc... some other html string etc... <p>something</p>`

I would like to print in a field this string formatted.
in android I use a webview...
in iphone a UIWebView...
but in BlackBerry?

Thanks ;)

Sergio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to support only RIM OS 5.0.0 and greater you can use [BrowserField.displayContent](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html#displayContent%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29) method.

Othervice try [BrowserFieldDemo & HttpConnection mockup approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878551/display-simple-html-in-a-native-blackberry-application/1881572#1881572)

Answer (score 2):

Please see the link for sample code / examples

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Creating_a_field_to_display_web_content_851601_11.jsp

Answer (score 1):

look to BrowserField

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field2/BrowserField.html