# how to use mjsip with j2me

Tags: java-me, voip

I want to make voip applicaton in j2me.I surfed about mjsip2ME. I want to use mjsip with my application. Can any one suggest me for how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a [tutorial](http://mjsip.org/download/mjsip_minitutorial_01.pdf), but it is kinda incomplete at the moment, as it does not contain source code, and some sections are labeled "TO DO". However, it contains the list of methodw, with descriptions and a quick, general help.

There's also some info on the web not on the official site, but I hope you're not afraid of chinese :/